# Can I change the type of a SharedPreferences variable safely?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a value saved in `SharedPreferences` that is a `float`. I tried to save this as a `int` after some design changes, but I cam getting a `ClassCastException`. The exception is thrown when I try to load this value.

The offending line: `preferences.getInt(myKey, myDefaultValue)`

Which was changed from: preferences.getFloat(myKey, myDefaultValue)`

Is there a safe way to load from this key and overwrite this value without having to clear my cache? Or will I need to create a totally new key?

Comment: You could get the float and then cast it to int, but that will be not needed in future versions as you have change your design so, delete the app or clear the data.

Comment: @Gonzalo the issue is that if the app is already published, I do not wish to have every user uninstall and then reinstall the app, or clear their cache, before they can use the app again

Comment: Sorry I thought you were on debug, not released yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should remove the value from preferences first.

Call

```
Editor.remove(String key);
```

and then set your value.

It also depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to store 'int' in settings, and then store there a 'float', and then 'int' again, the answer in NO, NEVER DO LIKE THAT!

If you just changed the variable type during development before any production, then you can just clear the app data and work with new variable without needing to clear it in code.

But if you've already deployed your application and now you want to change the variable type, then yes, you can do it and use .remove() method.

Comment: So is the proper solution to create a new key for the `SharedPreferences` and abandon the old one?

Comment: @h_k, it depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are trying to store int in settings, and then store there a float, and then int again, the answer in NO, NEVER DO LIKE THAT!

Comment: The value saved to preferences has always been a float. But now I'd like to switch to an integer instead for future releases.

Comment: @h_k, but if you just changed the variable type forever, then you can just clear the app data and work with new variable without needing to clear it.

Comment: @h_k, but if you've already deployed your application and now you want to change the variable type, then yes, you can do it and use .remove() method.

Comment: So call .remove() before loading from Preferences, then save as integer when my save function occurs. I can use the same key. I see no problem with this... I will go give it a try.

Comment: This solution appears to work correctly. I will need to continue testing to make sure it is safe, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In my case my app is already published and could not changed the old type of `SharedPreference` I had to surround the call with a `try-catch` for `ClassCastException`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use another key in this case. It looks safer for me. If you use the same key you have to put `Editor.remove(String key);` everywhere before putting the new value. And you have to remember that you can't just call `getInt()` method without wrapping it to try-catch. It may be not obvious for somebody who will edit the code later.